# Determine whether an element exists in XML to Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I'm using Amazon MWS and I was finally able to parse through the ListOrder response, but I have a problem. If there are over 100 orders, it will put a "NextToken" element in the 3rd level. I keep trying to find it, but whenever I run my code, it shows up null even though I know it's there (by looking at the actual XML generated in the response). To clear things up, here's an XML sample (irrelevant Elements redacted) and the code I'm using to read it.

```
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01">
    <ListOrdersResult>
        <NextToken>let's just pretend this is a nice token :)</NextToken>
    </ListOrdersResult>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

And the code:

```
            XElement nextToken = null;
            XDocument responseXMLDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);                
            XNamespace ns = "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01";
            nextToken = responseXMLDoc.Root.Element(ns + "NextToken");

            if (nextToken != null)
            {
                hasNext = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more pages!");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
```

Every time I run this, even though  is always there, I receive a null. I actually have to define the XElement in a parent scope so I can use it later.

Some things I've tried:

- Removed "root" from responseXMLDoc.Root.Element
- Didn't use the namespace in (ns + "NextToken)

There will only ever be one NextToken element in a request, and I just need the token from it so I can call the request again with the token - and keep repeating until there is no "NextToken".

**Update:** I'm certain I am getting the syntax wrong, I just can't seem to put my finger on the problem. With the same sample, trying

```
XElement listOrdersResult = responseXMLDoc.Root.Element(ns + "ListOrdersResult");
```

will also return a null value! I've read a bunch of questions on the Linq/XML topics here, and that's where I learned most of the syntax. Still not getting any results.

**Update 2:** Thanks to Brad Cunningham for the answer!

To fix the namespace issue I changed the following [the root node always has the xmlns attribute (and only that attribute):

```
String docNameSpace = responseXMLDoc.Root.FirstAttribute.Value.ToString();
XNamespace ns = docNameSpace;
```

And changing the following gives me the element I'm looking for:

```
nextToken = responseXMLDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "NextToken").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace is incorrect in your example (maybe a copy and paste error just for the example)

NextToken has a namespace of

`https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01`

However you are looking for a namespace of

`http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01`

Also using Element will only return the element if it is a immediate child of the parent element.

You should use Descendants if you don't know what level the node will be at

This works for me

```
XDocument responseXMLDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
XNamespace ns = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-01-01";
XElement nextToken = responseXMLDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "NextToken").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the incorrect namespace! Is there something I have to do to get FirstOrDefault() [I'm using C#].

Comment: Add using System.Linq to the top of your file